# Unable to boot MacOS Catalina after removing and re-adding VDI

Tags: macos, boot, virtualbox, uefi

I was successfully running Virtualbox MacOS Catalina guest. But I needed more space on the volume to upgrade to Big Sur. So I attempted to expand the size of the system volume (which may have been my first mistake), which wasn't successful. So I decided to tried to create another bigger VDI disk and clone the OS to the larger disk. I detached the disk from the VM but I wasn't successful in cloning the disk. So I reattached the original disk back to the Guest but now it only boots to the UEFI Interface. I attached the original disk to a second MacOS guest and the disk looks normal in diskutil, but I'm very much a newbie on the ins and outs of the new AFPS partition/Container system.

I'm a Windows guy and I've researched the APFS Container info, but there are many aspects that are still a mystery to me, i.e., how the volumes share the partition space, adding/removing disks from the OS, and the details of the MacOS boot process.

Any suggestions on how to use the UEFI interface to enable me to boot from the disk image?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: macOS doesn't use UEFI, so I'm a bit stuck as to exactly what it is you're doing. Also, Big Sur doesn't like being cloned; see https://bombich.com/blog/2021/05/19/beyond-bootable-backups-adapting-recovery-strategies-evolving-platform

Comment: Well, that is what VB appears to use as the boot manager. Any way I managed to get it fixed by mounting and booting from a bootable MacOS ISO. After checking the disk integrity while in the booted ISO. That seems to have fixed either the boot manager config or the boot sector on the disk. (I'm a little hazy on the exact details of that level of the process.) I could go into more detail, if it will help other users here.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to the bombich article. Very informative. I was cloning Catalina and then I was going to upgrade to Big Sur. That seems to work. YMMV.